# Change size of XML component when it is clicked upon

Tags: android, xml, button, kotlin

I don't have any code. However, for example, if I had a button and wanted it to go from 50dp to 100dp when it is clicked, how could I do that? I want to develop in Kotlin, and I am new to this and only 16 :). I am open to any suggestions to help me learn, but please help with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tôi does not use Android (Kotlin), it is only with Andorid (java) that think kotlin code also equivalent in the java construct other languages. in java you can use:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) myButton.getLayoutParams();
//RelativeLayout.LayoutParams or LinearLayout.LayoutParams or v.v...
lp.width = 100;
lp.height = 100;
myButton.setLayoutParams(lp)
```

Comment: thank you for the response, so quickly I will look into this one. You do not understand how appreciative I am, thank you fr.

Comment: nothing, 1 note small, 100 the other is not 100dp it is exactly 100px on the application screen, if you want 100dp you have to put 100dp in the dimens.xml file then you can use it

Comment: oh okay yeah I was wondering about how to do that, thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Every view has a LayoutParam.  This object holds info about how it is placed in its parent-  the layout_XXX attributes in the xml.  So you just need to change its height, then tell it to lay itself out again:

```
view.getLayoutParams().height = new height;
view.requestLayout();
```

Comment: thank you man, really!! I will look into it, youre amazing fr

Comment: Hey, could you use this in an example. As if lets say I had this code  myButton.setOnClickListener{
            
        }                                                                                                                            I want it to change to 100dp once it is clicked, would I just put  myButton.setOnClickListener{
            view.getLayoutParams().height = new height //is this where i put the height i want it to turn it?                                                                                      view.requestLayout();
        } I am new I'm sorry

Comment: Thank you!! I got it, you both really helped me. Wow thank you fr